# Reporting $\chi^2$ test results in APA format

Tags: chi-squared-test, excel, independence

I'm trying to report the results of my chi-square test for independence in APA format but these results don't resemble the examples I've seen especially the 4 digits before the period in the chi-square test results i.e. 9355.19 and 9556.44.  Am I doing this right?

> "the χ2 tests showed significant
>   results in the association of this
>   knowledge with years professional of
>   experience χ2  (4, N = 302) = 9355.19,
>   p = 0.83 and with professional level
>   χ2 (4, N = 302) = 9556.44, p = 0.30."

**These are the values:**

```
         I agree I disagree I don't know |Total
Level 1      141         26           26 |  193
Level 2       29          5           12 |   46 
Level 3       43         10           10 |   63 
-----------------------------------------------
Total        213         41           48 |  302
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Such large statistics, with 4 df and non-significant p-values, look rather strange. How were they obtained? Apparently, they come from a cross-classification (contingency) table? Could you add a little bit of context on your study and show us the figures?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes these are from a contingency table that crossed tow questions.  I'm trying to post the numbers but it isn't working.  I'm going to try posting the results in one and the expected values in the next.  Thanks.

Comment: These are the values                                                   I agree I disagree I don't know Total
Level 1 141 26 26 193
Level 2 29 5 12 46
Level 3 43 10 10 63
 213 41 48 302

Comment: These are the expected values                                                   I agree I disagree I don't know Total
Level 1 136.1225166 26.20198675 30.67549669 193
Level 2 32.44370861 6.245033113 7.311258278 46
Level 3 44.43377483 8.552980132 10.01324503 63
 213 41 48 302

Comment: You have a problem with your $\chi^2$ statistic. I don't have the same result. What software are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Given the data you posted in your comment, here are the results I get from R:

```
> x <- matrix(c(141,29,43,26,5,10,26,12,10), nc=3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  141   26   26
[2,]   29    5   12
[3,]   43   10   10
> chisq.test(x)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x 
X-squared = 4.8007, df = 4, p-value = 0.3084
```

So, the $\chi^2$  statistic is actually 4.80. (The expected values are the ones you gave in your comment.)

Comment: Hmmm. Thank you. I'm using excel (French version) and I get 0.308364587 for the p value.  that's when I use the function CHISQ.TEST and when I enter the degrees of freedom and the p value into the KHIDEUX.INVERSE i get 9556.441991

Comment: @alis There's a problem with this value. I get 4.800702 for the above p-value (`qchisq(0.308364587, 4, lower.tail=F)`).

Comment: @chl You mean 4.8 is the statistic and .308 is the p-value, of course.  (There's no error in your comment, just a potential for misunderstanding because it can easily be misinterpreted.)

Comment: Let's emphasize, too, that this result is **not** significant.  Therefore the text should read something like "The χ2 test did not indicate a significant association between knowledge and professional level (χ2(4)=4.80, N=302, p=0.30)."

Comment: @alis Excel's `=CHIINV(0.308364587, 4)` function gives the correct answer, 4.800701.

Comment: @whuber Yes I should have been more careful when replying.

Comment: Thank you!  I just redid the calculation on excel and it did work.  I don't see why it came out wrong the first time.  And yes I agree it is not significant.  Thank you again.  Everyone.

Comment: Actually I do understand now.  In the =CHIINV function I entered the number from the Chi-square table 9,488 where I should have entered 4 degrees of freedom.  Sorry my mistake.  But I'm amazed and very grateful for the attentiveness on this site and the excellence of your help.  I may be back with more questions later.